# Select parts of a string till a certain character and store in an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am trying to select parts of a string till a certain character, -----, and put them in an array. For eg. in the below paragraph I want to store from "Game..the", "next....player", "free....zone" and "or....career" in one array in php.

Gamers can also take on Blitz a wild, high-pressure challenge where players must race against the clock to reach the ----- next checkpoint before time runs out. Gamers who download the console versions can also play online for a limited period of 2 weeks from release, experiencing up to 16 player ----- free ride in a limited area of the Tsunami Reef zone ---- or challenging up to 6 other players in the Ocean Rush career

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
explode(" ----- ", $paragraph);
```

Comment: This gives me only from "next checkpoint....16 player". Sorry..tried it again. It works thanks.